# Sending a JSON object via Javascript POST request to a Rails controller

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, rspec, vue.js, capybara

I'm trying to submit a form in a Rails 5.1 app that uses Vue.js and Dropzone. During the `sendingEvent` I am using `JSON.stringify` on the object before sending it over to the controller. However, I don't feel this is the correct way to do it, as I am then having problems with using strong params in the controller.

**JS**:

```
import Vue from 'vue/dist/vue.esm'
import VueResource from 'vue-resource'
import vue2Dropzone from 'vue2-dropzone'

Vue.use(VueResource)

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  if(document.getElementById('listing-multistep') !== null) {
    Vue.http.headers.common['X-CSRF-Token'] = document.querySelector('input[name="authenticity_token"]').getAttribute('value');
    var listingForm = document.getElementById('listing_form');
    var listing = JSON.parse(listingForm.dataset.listing);
    var locale = document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].getAttribute('lang');
    const myForm = new Vue({
      el: '#listing-multistep',
      components: {
        vueDropzone: vue2Dropzone
      },
      data: function () {
        return {
          id: listing.id,
          locale: locale,
          slug: listing.slug,
          activeStep: 0,
          // More data
          dropzoneOptions: {
            url: `/${locale}/listings`,
            method: 'post',
            acceptedFiles: 'image/*',
            uploadMultiple: true,
            autoProcessQueue: false,
            parallelUploads: 15,
            maxFiles: 15,
            addRemoveLinks: true,
            thumbnailWidth: 150,
            maxFilesize: 5,
            dictDefaultMessage: "<i class='fa fa-cloud-upload'></i> Drop files here to upload (max. 15 files)",
            headers: { 'X-CSRF-Token': Vue.http.headers.common['X-CSRF-Token'] }
          }
        }
      },
      methods: {
        sendingEvent: function(file, xhr, formData) {
          // This function gets called by Dropzone upon form submission.
          var listingObj = this.setupListingObj()
          formData.append('listing', JSON.stringify(listingObj))
        },
        listingRedirect: function(files, response) {
          window.location = `/${this.locale}/listings/${response.slug}`
        },
        submitListing: function() {
          var numFiles = this.$refs.listingDropzone.getAcceptedFiles().length
          // If there are images to upload, use Dropzone
          // Else submit the form normally.
          if(numFiles > 0) {
            this.$refs.listingDropzone.processQueue()
          } else {
            var listingObj = this.setupListingObj()

            if(this.id === null) {
              // POST if it's a new listing
              this.$http.post(`/${this.locale}/listings`, {listing: listingObj}).then(
                response => {
                  window.location = `/${this.locale}/listings/${response.body.slug}`
              }, response => {
                console.log(response)
              })
            } else {
              // PUT if it's an existing listing
              this.$http.put(`/${this.locale}/listings/${this.slug}`, {listing: listingObj}).then(
                response => {
                  window.location = `/${this.locale}/listings/${response.body.slug}`
              }, response => {
                console.log(response)
              })
            }
          }
        },
        setupListingObj: function() {
          // do some processing...

          var listingObj = {
            id: this.id,
            name: this.name,
            // set more attributes
          }
          return listingObj
        },
      }
  }
});
```

as you can see I am using `formData.append('listing', JSON.stringify(listingObj))` on the `sendingEvent`.

My controller:

```
class ListingsController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @listing = Listing.new JSON.parse(params[:listing])
    @listing.owner = current_user
    respond_to do |format|
      if @listing.save
        format.html { redirect_to listing_path(@listing), notice: 'Listing was created successfully!' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @listing }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @listing.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  private

  def listing_params
    params.require(:listing).permit(
      :name,
      :bedrooms,
      :beds,
      :bathrooms,
      :price_cents,
      :price_currency,
      :property_type,
      :city,
      :state,
      :address,
      :lat,
      :lng,
      :description,
      :amenities => []
    )
  end
end
```

It seems to work in development, but when I run a test with this code in RSpec I get errors like:

```
Internal Server Error no implicit conversion of ActionController::Parameters into String
```

When I try to swap `@listing = Listing.new JSON.parse(listing_params)` it fails to work in development.

I have a feeling I'm not sending the form data across properly. What is the correct way to send the data over via Javascript to my Rails controller? Does it need to be strigified and then posted? How can I access it via strong params instead?

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE**

This is what my spec looks like:

```
RSpec.feature 'Listing owners can create new listings' do
  let(:owner) { create(:user, :owner) }

  before do
    login_as owner
    visit new_listing_path
  end

  scenario 'successfully', js: true do
    fill_in 'Property name', with: 'Example property'
    select 'Apartment', from: 'Property type'
    fill_in 'Address', with: 'Somewhere'
    click_button 'Next'

    fill_in 'Property description', with: Faker::Lorem.paragraph(2)
    click_button 'Create Listing'

    expect(page).to have_content 'Listing was created successfully!'
  end
end
```

I am using Chrome headless for these tests in order to parse the Vue.js stuff on the form. In my **rails_helper.rb** I have:

```
require 'spec_helper'
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'capybara/rails'
require 'capybara/rspec'
require 'pundit/rspec'
require 'selenium/webdriver'

RSpec.configure do |config|
  # ...
  Capybara.javascript_driver = :headless_chrome
end
```

and I have a **support/chrome_driver.rb** file with the following:

```
Capybara.register_driver(:headless_chrome) do |app|
  capabilities = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.chrome(
    chromeOptions: { args: %w[headless disable-gpu] }
  )

  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(
    app,
    browser: :chrome,
    desired_capabilities: capabilities
  )
end
```

Comment: `@listing = Listing.new JSON.parse(listing_params)` Does this fail to work in development or in test? Show how you pass parameters in RSpec

Comment: In development I get `TypeError (no implicit conversion of ActionController::Parameters into String)` when using `Listing.new JSON.parse(listing_params)`. I've updated the post with my spec and config as well.

Comment: See in the console log what params are passed to the controller in development. Also show `listing_params` implementation

Comment: Added `listing_params` to the post. In the logs I see the parameters passing properly but RSpec returns the error `Internal Server Error no implicit conversion of ActionController::Parameters into String`

Comment: Show the parameters from the console log

Comment: `Processing by ListingsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "listing"=>{"name"=>"Example property", "property_type"=>"apartment", "bedrooms"=>"1", "beds"=>"2", "bathrooms"=>"2", "price_currency"=>"usd", "price_cents"=>"210.0", "price_per_month"=>"", "city"=>"Some city", "state"=>"Some state", "address"=>"Blah blah 123", "lat"=>"", "lng"=>"", "description"=>"Similique et ea illo sint doloribus dolor maiores. Aut dolores dolorem."}, "map_search"=>"address", "commit"=>"Create Listing", "locale"=>"en"}`

Comment: You don't need `JSON.parse()` in the controller at all. `@listing = Listing.new(listing_params)`

Comment: Ah you might be right. I think I need `JSON.parse` when this code executes `if(numFiles > 0) {this.$refs.listingDropzone.processQueue()}` but not when the else condition runs.